# How observe a method String return value every second?

Tags: android, rx-java, rx-android

I need to observe a string that is an application's top package name and its on changes to something. I tried to do something like this:

```
getObservable()
                .distinctUntilChanged()
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread())
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .subscribeWith(disposableObserver);

public  Observable<String> getObservable() {
    return Observable.just(getTopPackageName()).delay(1000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS).repeat();
}
```

```
String getTopPackageName(){
   // return top package name;
}
```

I want to get the top package changes every second and if it's not changed and still the previous top package does nothing. I can't figure out how to do this

Answer (score 2):

Just change your `getObservable()` method:

```
public  Observable<String> getObservable() {
    return Observable.interval(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS).map(v -> getTopPackageName());
}
```